# How to get the active sprint information and extract the issues out of them through python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jira

I am trying to build an app where I can have productivity of each user working in the team. For that I am trying to extract the active sprint board info but getting an error '**errorMessages":["To update this sprint, you must either have the Manage Sprints or the Edit Sprints permission for all of the following projects:.....'**. I am using the jira api and trying to access the sprints with the board id (which I am able to do) but unable to get the sprint_info because of the above error. Are there any suggestions as to how can i extract such information.*emphasized text*

```
from jira import JIRA, JIRAError
jira = JIRA(options={'server': 'https://jira.com/'}, basic_auth=("user", "*****"))
board_id = '700'
jira_sprints = jira.sprints(board_id)
for jira_sprint in jira_sprints:
   sprint_info = jira.sprint_info(board_id, jira_sprint.id) 
print(sprint_info)
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessarily an API/Python issue. The problem is the user you are logging in as does not have permissions for the project the sprint belongs to. You should check what permissions you have, and get the needed ones, (those listed in the error message) added.